# Cannot read property 'urlslist' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, web, mongoose

Here "user" is a collection of usernames, email, password, and an array of id. These ids belong to a collection "urllist".when I am doing `console.log(resp.urlslist)` it is giving an array of objects. but when passing the same result using `res.render("finalsite",{linklist:resp.urlslist})` then `urlslist` is null error is occurring:
So Please Help me.

```
app.get("/finalsite/:use", function(req, res) {
    user.findOne({
            username: req.params.use
        })
        .populate("urlslist")
        .exec()
        .then((resp) => {
            console.log(resp.urlslist);
            res.render("finalsite", {
                linklist: resp.urlslist
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

Here is my `EJS` template in which I am passing the data in the form of an array. And printing each object's title using the `forEach` function.

```
<%- include("partials/header")%><title></title></head>

<%linklist.forEach(function(link){%>

<a href="<%=link.url%>" class="btn" target="_blank"><%=link.title%></a>
<%})%><%- include("partials/footer")%>
```

My Schema for `user` and `urllist` is

```
const urllistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    url: String,
    user_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "user"
    }
});
const urllist = mongoose.model("urllist", urllistSchema);
const urlslistSchema = urllist.schema;
const linktrSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    urlslist: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "urllist",
    }]
});

const user = mongoose.model("user", linktrSchema);
```

Comment: Can you show us the `ejs`-template?

Comment: added the ejs template.

Comment: Can you also add the Schema definitions for `User` and `UrlsList`?

Comment: added the User schema and Urllist Schema.